# Why is 'arg' a list inside the function but returned as a string?

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, return

```
def strip_split(arg):
    arg = arg.split(", ")
    return arg


users = ["admin, adm1n"]

for user in users:
    strip_split(user)
    print(user)
    print(user[0])
```

This is a very simple program but I can't work out why arg is a list inside the function (I've tested using print(arg)), but when 'arg' is returned it comes out as a string.

I expected that when I 'print(user)' the output is '["admin, adm1n"]' and 'print(user[0])' is 'admin', however I get 'admin, adm1n' and 'a'.

Comment: `strip_split(user)` doesn't modify `user` and doesn't do anything with the value returned by `strip_split` (which is the modified `arg` from inside the function).  Did you mean to do `user = strip_split(user)`?

Comment: Assigning to `arg` does not modify the value referenced by `user`; it only makes `arg` reference a *different* value.

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting user to the result of the function:

```py
def strip_split(arg):
    arg = arg.split(", ")
    return arg


users = ["admin, adm1n"]

for user in users:
    user = strip_split(user)
    print(user)
    print(user[0])
```

Gives your expected results as you're assigned the value back.  Strings are immutable so you can't *change* them as such, just assign new values.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `strip_split(user)` is doing `"admin, adm1n".split(", ")` which gives `['admin', 'adm1n']`. But, you are not assigning it to `user` or any other variable.

So it is giving this output:

```
for user in users:
    print(user)

#'admin, adm1n'
```

If you want the result you have to assign it to a variable or itself:

```
for user in users:
    user = strip_split(user)
    print(user)
    print(user[0])

#output
['admin', 'adm1n']
admin
```